# Predicting population of bugs with differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem on population modelling using differential equations:

> Initially, there are 200 bugs. After two days, there are 360 bugs. The birth
>   rate for this kind of bug is 150% per day. Assuming that the
>   population is given by a logistic model:
>
> a) How many bugs are there after 3 days? 
>   b) How many bugs are there after a long time?

I have assumed that the death rate is directly proportional to the birth rate. Hence, the differential equation that describes the growth of the bug population is:

\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dT} = BN - SN^2
\end{align}

I try to retrieve the equation for $ N:$

\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{BN-SN^2} = dT
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\int\frac{dN}{BN-SN^2} = \int dT
\end{align}

I realised this would  be overly complex. Furthermore, S is an unknown, making the equation more complicated.

I do not know what else I could do from here to solve this problem. Could anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Use partial fractions to integrate the left-hand side.

Comment: @MichaelLee Won't Partial fractions be difficult to perform since S is an unknown?

Comment: No, just do it algebraically. $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}N}{N(B-SN)} = \int \frac{1}{BN}+\frac{S}{B(B-SN)}\,\mathrm{d}N = \frac{\log(N)-\log(B-SN)}{B}$$